# kafka topic has two avro classes

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to understand more about what the schema-registry keeps per schema.  Where can I go, or what tool can I use, to know the name of the java package that is associated with the class that was created by the avro file.  The specific piece would be the `"namespace"` element of the `.avsc` file.  Is there a command line tool or any other way I can find this metadata out for a given schema in the schema registry?  I know it's in the `.avsc` file, but I want to find this out from the shema registry only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`GET /subjects/(string: subject)/versions/(versionId: version)/schema`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html#get--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions-(versionId-%20version)-schema) API to get the avro schema and get the namespace out from the json response.